# spring boot app does not reload despite spring boot dev tools already installed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reload, spring-boot-devtools

I already included this dependency in my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Changed to "Build project automatically" in the Compiler/Settings, reloaded Maven projects, rebuilt the project but when I made changes in the Controller it doesn't seem to reload the application (I cannot see changes) though I saw this in the terminal

```
[  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
```

Comment: Which ide, intellij?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this command in application.properties:

```
 spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=true
```

check this resource:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools